# Is there some way to draw over active windows?

Tags: windows

I want to draw over active windows. For example, suppose I'm playing a game. I want to be able to draw *over* the game window to remind me of something later, but I don't want to take a screenshot, because it obviously won't display the game while I'm playing it.

What I need is to be able to draw over a window, but still be able to interact with it, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Could you maybe try and be more specific? Do you want to draw *within* a game, interacting with the game's physical properties, then come back, for example play the same level again, and see that?

Comment: No, I only want to draw so I can see it while playing the level, while I'm drawing, I don't need the game to capture my mouse clicks.

Comment: Whenever I am in that sort of situation, I usually just draw on the screen with a water-soluble marker. (NB, I have a glass-screen CRT monitor.) Another option might be to tape a transparency sheet to the screen and draw on that with a marker.

Comment: Bobson: I don't have one of these pens :(

Comment: @M2B a dry erase marker might work, but test it.  Question, do you want this to show up only when you run a certain program and at certain points in the game?

Comment: @uSlackr: I don't need anything fancy, it could show up at all times, I will only use it while playing the game so it doesn't need to only be activated when the game window is focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is called "on-screen annotation", for which there are many products available.

The article [On-screen annotation](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/On-screen_annotation) lists and describes many such products, some free and some commercial : Presentation Marker,
Netop pointer,
Annotate Pro,
Screen Marker,
Presentation Pointer,
Screen Marker,
Ultimate Pen,
Ink2Go,
HeyeLighter.

It also points to [Wikipedia's comparison of web annotation systems](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Web_annotation) and also to the Makeuseof [list of top web annotation tools](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/web-annotation-tools-research-annotate-collaborate/).

Comment: I have used ScreenMarker before and it does the job well. It's free, lightweight, and seems to fulfill M28's requirements too. Note however, that the link for ScreenMarker provided in harrymc's first link looks dead. You can find it [here](http://www.tucows.com/preview/509739).

Answer (score 0):

You could take the screen shot, annotate and place the pic on a second monitor; or you could follow @Bobson's advice with plastic screen cover and a dry erase marker.

Comment: I don't have a second monitor neither a marker :(

Comment: you may have to spend a couple bucks for a marker.  Otherwise it appears you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Epic Pen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epicpen/) is another option - this one open source.  No ability to save/restore, very simple, but meets your needs as listed.